# Let users sort posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, loops

I’d like to create a page for filtering posts based on a number of criteria.

I can work with `wp_query` and deliver posts quite easily, my problem is that I can’t figure out (nor can I find any answers online about this, believe me I looked) how to let users do this.

Take this for example, returns the posts in order of price (custom field meta value) from highest to lowest with 33 posts.

```
<?php 

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => 33,
   'meta_key'=>'Price',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => DESC
) );

?>

<?php if ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $featuredPosts->have_posts() ) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>

<article <?php post_class('item-post block'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<h2 class="price-title"><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>

</article> <!-- end div post -->

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, even after reading and googling, I’ll be damned if I can figure out how I’d implement this on the front end for users to filter posts.

I mean, I know you can append to the URLs in Wordpress to alter the order of posts, but in this context I’m totally lost.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

$by_price = esc_url(add_query_arg(array(
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => ASC
)));
$by_date = esc_url(add_query_arg(array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => DESC
)));

?>

<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $by_price;?>">Order by price</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $by_date;?>">Order by date</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I’m trying to achieve is actually quite simple as well, let the user choose the category, choose the price range (guessing I’d write something in JQuery to deliver a value into an field), set the number of results they’d like to be returned.

I’ve tried googling *everything* under the sun I can think of for this, no dice.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Simple Custom Post Order plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/).

It is using AJAX and JavaScript, you don’t have to load anything else. You have to just drag and drop the posts.

Comment: This is for backend filtering and not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I update the code to make it clear:

---I do not think meta_key would be auto-pickup---

functions.php

```
...

    $whitList = array(
       'price' => array(
         'posts_per_page' => 33,
         'meta_key'=>'price',
         'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
         'order' => ASC
       ),
       'date' => array(
         'posts_per_page' => 33,
         'orderby'=>'date',
         'order' => DESC
       )
    );
...
```

Your first loop php:

```
<?php 

gloabl $whitList; //to use the $whitList in your functions.php.

$aryQuery = $whitList[$_REQUEST['orderby']] ? $whitList[$_REQUEST['orderby']] : $whitList['price'];

$featuredPosts = new WP_Query( $aryQuery ); 

....
....
?>
```

For your list page:

```
<ul>
<?php
   gloabl $whitList; //to use the $whitList in your functions.php.
   foreach( $whitList as $orderby => $aryOrderBySettings){
      ?>
      <li> <a href="<?php echo esc_url(add_query_arg('orderby', $orderby));?>">Order by <?php echo $orderby;?></a></li>
      <?php
   }
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does the second part need to be inside the loop?

Comment: Unless I put the second part inside the loop from the first part it never appears on the page.

Comment: Sorry, the define of `$whitList` has to sit in a global place, such as: functions.php; otherwise, second php still cannot find `$whitList`

Comment: Oh I see, so I can just keep adding new arrays like 'popular' => array (
      'posts_per_page' => 33,
      'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
      'order' => 'DESC'
     
     ) ?

And it's possible to add things like specific ranges to the price?
Btw, it only works if I remove 'gloabl $whitList; //to use the $whitList in your functions.php.' from the list page part.

Comment: Yes, you can put price range in, please check http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters - take extra care about the `meta_query` and `compare`. However, the idea behind it is - do not accept data supply by client side, client side only supply the command which predefined in your white list.

Comment: Uh, this is so complicated. I tried this and it just displays by date.  'Under £22' => array( 
     'meta_key' => 'price', 
     'meta_value_num' => '22', 
     'meta_compare' => '<=' 
     
     )
And it takes the title from the array as the list items title, so I can't use £ or $ signs in the name.

Comment: £ is html special character = &pound;

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_GET` parameters is the way to go here. First of all you'll want to allow your visitors access to these add these variables. The link approach is fine, overall, so we can generate augmented links by using the [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to tack on extra parameters to the current URL.

```
<?php
    $urla = add_query_arg( 'sort' => 'price', 'asc' => '1' );
    $urld = add_query_arg( 'sort' => 'price', 'asc' => '0' );
?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>">Sort by price (asc)</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>">Sort by price (desc)</a>
```

When clicked, the tacked on variables can thus be detected:

```
<?php
    // Get an allowed sort variable and the order
    $sort = isset( $_GET['sort'] ) && in_array( $_GET['sort'], array( 'price' ) ) )
            ? $_GET['sort'] : null;
    $order = isset( $_GET['asc'] ) && $_GET['asc'] == '0' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
?>
```

Now you would augment your main query with the data you just retrieved. If you're using the default way of querying posts on a page you should be able to get away with [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), although it is [not recomended](http://stephenharris.info/die-query_posts-die/). And, if you're using a custom loop, simply inject the new arguments into it:

```
<?php
    $args = array();
    switch ( $sort ):
        case 'price':
            $args['order'] = $order;
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'price';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    endswitch;

    $defaults = array( 'posts_per_page' => 33 );
    $query = new WP_Query( wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ) );
?>
```

You can add more variables, by creating more URLs and buttons to press, and more cases in the switch statement to extend the basic example above.

The first piece of code would go wherever you want your buttons to appear. The second piece of code goes before the third one, which goes before outputting the results.